# dates in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to see how long the client spend time connecting to our website daily.
My table source in created as below and contains the data as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE source_ (
"nbr" numeric (10),
"begdate" timestamp,
"enddate" timestamp,
"str" varchar(35))
;
INSERT INTO source_
("nbr", "begdate", "enddate", "str")
VALUES
(111, '2019-11-25 07:00:00', '2019-11-25 08:00:00', 'TMP123'),
  (222, '2019-03-01 12:04:02', '2019-03-01 12:05:02', 'SOC'),
  (111, '2019-11-25 19:00:00', '2019-11-25 19:30:00', 'TMP12'),
  (444, '2020-02-11 22:00:00', '2020-02-12 02:00:00', 'MARATEN'),
  (444, '2020-02-11 23:00:00', '2020-02-12 01:00:00', 'MARA12'),
  (444, '2020-02-12 13:00:00', '2020-02-12 14:00:00', 'MARA12'),
  (444, '2020-02-12 07:00:00', '2020-02-12 08:00:00', 'MARA1222')
 
;


create table target_ (nbr numeric (10), date_ int(10), state varchar(30), terms interval);
```

I did an attempt below, but as you can see i associated the date_ (day of the event) to the beddate which is not always true see (4th row)  when the event is between two days.

```
INSERT INTO target_
(nbr, date_, state,  terms)
 select
   nbr,
   DATE_TRUNC('day', begdate) as date_,
   state,
   sum(term) as terms
   from (
  select
      nbr, begdate,
      (case
            when trim(str) ~ '^TMP' then 'TMP'
            when trim(str) ~ '^MARA' then 'MARATEN'
            else 'SOC'
       end) as state,
 (enddate - begdate)as term from source_ ) X

   group by nbr, date_, state;
```

**expected output**

111   2019-11-25 00:00:00+00  TMP 90

222   2019-03-01 00:00:00+00  SOC 60

444   2020-02-11 00:00:00+00  MARATEN 180

444   2020-02-12 00:00:00+00  MARATEN 300

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you also add the expected results?

Comment: thank you @JimJones i updated my original post to add it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `generate_series()` to expand the periods and then aggregate:

```
select gs.dte, 
       (case when trim(str) ~ '^TMP' then 'TMP'
             when trim(str) ~ '^MARA' then 'MARATEN'
             else 'SOC'
        end) as state,
       sum( least(s.enddate, gs.dte + interval '1 day') - greatest(s.begdate, gs.dte))
from source s cross join lateral
     generate_series(begdate::date, enddate::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
group by state, gs.dte
order by gs.dte, state;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2b5b9516c5ba7c70592bd87b9108060b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, what is lateral please? @gordon Linoff

Comment: @direction . . . A good place to start is the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html).  However, they are basically like correlated subqueries that can return multiple rows and multiple columns.

Comment: tahnk you, please is there a way to convert the dte to number of seconds (int). I saw this function extract(epoch from (dte))

Comment: @direction . . . That function will convert a date to the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

Comment: i didn't succeded to implement it in the same code that you propoed.  can you help please?

Comment: @direction . . . I have included a db<>fiddle that shows the code working.

Comment: Thank you but saw your code, i didn't find this function thats why extract(epoch from (dte)) :/ . didn't succed to added .

Comment: @direction . . . It is not needed.  This answers the question that you asked.